# SQL Server - replace string by appearance

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

Got a small question ... this is test data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestReplace (
    Description NVARCHAR(500)
    ,ParamValue1 INT
    ,ParamValue2 INT
    ,ParamValue3 INT
    );

INSERT INTO #TestReplace (Description)
VALUES ('This sentence has no parameteres, and it should be shown like this');

INSERT INTO #TestReplace (
    Description
    ,ParamValue1
    )
VALUES (
    'This sentence has only one parametere, and it should be shown right here {param} with rest of text'
    ,100
    );

INSERT INTO #TestReplace (
    Description
    ,ParamValue1
    ,ParamValue2
    )
VALUES (
    'This sentence has two parameteres, one here {param} and one here {param}, show full sentence'
    ,100
    ,200
    );

INSERT INTO #TestReplace (
    Description
    ,ParamValue1
    ,ParamValue2
    ,ParamValue3
    )
VALUES (
    'This sentence has all parameteres, here {param} and here {param} and there {param}'
    ,100
    ,200
    ,300
    );
```

In my sentence I have occurrences of a word `{param}` sometimes or never ... and columns `ParamValue1`, `ParamValue2`, `ParamValue3` ... How could I replace first occurences of a word `{param}` with value of column `ParamValue1`, second word `{param}` with value of column `ParamValue2` and third with value of column `ParamValue3` ... I am unable to change word `{param}` into `{param1}`, `{param2}` and `{param3}` and go with simple replace

So far I managed to replace only first occurance ...

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('{param}', DESCRIPTION) > 0
            THEN STUFF(DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('{param}', DESCRIPTION), LEN('{param}'), ParamValue1)
        ELSE DESCRIPTION
        END
FROM #TestReplace
```

This was managed easily in Oracle ([Oracle - replace string by appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375951/oracle-replace-string-by-appearance))

Comment: SQL Server doesn't natively support REGEX, and thus doesn't support REGEX replacement. If you do want something like this, you'll likely want to look at a CLR function.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Currently on Microsoft SQL Server 2012, but able to update if needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can chain these together using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(v3.DESCRIPTION, v2.DESCRIPTION, v1.DESCRIPTION, tr.DESCRIPTION)
FROM #TestReplace tr CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN tr.Description LIKE '%{param}%'
                   THEN STUFF(tr.DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('{param}', tr.DESCRIPTION), LEN('{param}'), tr.ParamValue1)
              END)
     ) v1(description) CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN v1.Description LIKE '%{param}%'
                   THEN STUFF(v1.DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('{param}', v1.DESCRIPTION), LEN('{param}'), tr.ParamValue2)
              END)
     ) v2(description) CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN v2.Description LIKE '%{param}%'
                   THEN STUFF(v2.DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('{param}', v2.DESCRIPTION), LEN('{param}'), ParamValue3)
              END)
     ) v3(description);
```